# How to remove dynamic module Bundle and minification in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, optimization, bundle

I'm not using the bundling and minification feature of asp.net mvc, and I would like to know if it's possible to completely turn it off. I already did

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

But I still see the module in the module list at runtime.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: just dont add System.web.optimization in your projects. So, bundling will be disabled. Remove the namespace from web.config too.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove it via the web.config-file:

```
<modules>
  <remove name="BundlingModule" /> <!-- not 100% sure on the name, you might need to look that up -->
</modules>
```

Comment: Hello it doesn't work.
neither
<remove name="BundlingModule" />
nor
<remove name="__DynamicModule_System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule, System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_3de79370-4976-472b-b77e-334b8c8ee21f"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove it. The dynamic module BundleModule is defined in assembly info `[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(System.Web.Optimization.PreApplicationStartCode), "Start")]`

So when the assembly is loaded, PreApplicationStart ensures that the module is defined.